# How to properly sign in using Firebase Authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After a user creates an account, is he/she already signed in after createUserWithEmailAndPassword() returns successful? Or right after the account creation I need to then sign the user in with signInWithEmailAndPassword()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the account, the user is automatically signed in. See the section at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

This is assuming the account creation was successful. You can check by using:

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null
```

Comment: No problem. If you have a minute, mark the answer as accepted so future searchers can find it easily.